# How inform ChildController inside ParentController in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a code similar to the code below:

```
  <div ng-controller="ParentController">
    <button>A</button>
    <button>B</button>
    <button>C</button>
    <div ng-controller="ChildController">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="name in nameList">{{name}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

`ChildController` area as default is hidden. I want to show child area when one of the buttons inside parent area clicked. Also I need to call different functions base on the clicked button and then assign the result to `$scope.nameList` inside `ChildController` and then display data.
I was wondering what would be the best practice to do this job.

Comment: Did you get to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `$broadcast` method on the `$scope` to do this or a simple `$scope` inheritance. Let's start with the first approach.

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller="ParentController">
    <button ng-click="showSection('sectionA')">Show Section A</button>
    <button ng-click="showSection('sectionB')">Show Section B</button>
    <div ng-controller="ChildController">
        <section ng-if="showSection.sectionA">SOME CONTENT HERE</section>
        <section ng-if="showSection.sectionB">SOME CONTENT HERE</section>
    </div>
</div>
```

**ParentController:**

```
function ParentControler($scope) {

    $scope.showSection = function (section) {
        $scope.$broadcast('ParentController.showSection', section);
    }

}
```

**ChildController:**

```
function ChildController($scope) {

    $scope.showSection = {
        sectionA: false,
        sectionB: false
    };

    $scope.$on('ParentController.showSection', (event, section) => {
        $scope.showSection[section] = true;
    }

}
```

Or you could very simply use `$scope` inheritance, which in this case would be more than enough.

HTML would be identical to the previous example.

**ParentController:**

```
function ParentControler($scope) {

    $scope.showSection = {
        sectionA: false,
        sectionB: false
    };

    $scope.showSection = function (section) {
        $scope.showSection[section] = true;
    }

}
```

**ChildController:**

```
function ChildController($scope) {

    //

}
```

It depends on what you are trying to achieve in the long run. If you are looking for a simple solution just to do this king of thing, use the `$scope` inheritance. If you need a more elaborate communication between those two controllers, you might opt-in for the event method.